# iOS Navigation Controller Back Button Causing Glitch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a navigation view that contains a tableview. If one of the tableview items is clicked, the navigation controller passes the user to the detail view.

This usually works perfectly. However, if the user clicks the back button from the detail view and moves back and forth between the tableview and detail view too quickly, the app will sometimes become glitchy.

This glitch occurs rarely, but when it does, the back button makes the view transition to the left, but it just shows the detail view again. Then I need to press the back button again in order to actually go back to the list view.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Or is there a bit of code I can post to help resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you added that back button or u r talking about default back button. If you added that then paste that code.

Comment: this happens sometimes if you're calling that function with perform selector.

Comment: its the default back button that comes with it. The error seems to come up when the user clicks back before the view has a chance to load fully.

Comment: If it is taking so long to load your view then make userInterfaceEnable of your view as FALSE till your view is loaded properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//in viewwillappear
appDelegate.window.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
[self performSelector:@selector(userInteraction) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];


-(void)userInteraction
{
    appDelegate.window.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I think mean YES/NO and not TRUE/FALSE